# Is there any syntax in Python to check whether an integer input by the user contains a specific digit in it?

Tags: python, syntax

So I basically want to know whether there is any syntax that can recognize if the integer entered by the user contains some specified digit

For example: 23 has the digit 3.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the digit to a string, then check if the digit is in the string.

For example, I want to check if 9 is in the number.

```
x = str(50192301)
if '9' in x:
    return True
```